# Count nested select using join and by month

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, count

Hi I have three tables here is all
First. **count_internets**

```
id| company_id | item_id | created_at
1 | 1          |    1    | 2020-10-14 |
2 | 1          |    2    | 2020-10-15 |
3 | 2          |    4    | 2020-10-16 |
4 | 2          |    5    | 2020-11-20 |
5 | 1          |    1    | 2020-11-22 |
6 | 1          |    1    | 2020-11-23 |
7 | 2          |    5    | 2020-11-23 |
```

Second **compaies**

```
id | name
1  | Company 1
2  | Company 2
```

Third **items**

```
id  | name      | company_id
1   | Product 1 |    1
2   | Product 2 |    1
3   | Product 4 |    2
4   | Product 5 |    5
```

I want to get infomartion how many items sold during one month grouping by company like below

```
| Company   | Products  | Month | Count 
| Company 1 | Product 1 | OCT   | 1
| Company 1 | Product 2 | OCT   | 1
| Company 1 | Product 1 | NOV   | 1
| Company 1 | Product 4 | OCT   | 1
| Company 2 | Product 5 | NOV   | 2
```

I tried many SQL queries, but I can not solve. Please help to solve this query.

Comment: Yes MySQL, created_at = datetime, I just inserted only date texts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work

```
SELECT c.name as company, i.name as products, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) as month, count(*)
FROM count_internets
JOIN companies as c on company_id = c.id
JOIN items as i on item_id = i.id
GROUP BY company, products, month
```

Be aware that if that the query extract only the month (so no difference between years). If you need the year too you have to extract it `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)) as year`.

But your example is not very clear, company 1 didn't sell product 3. Furthermore, what's the meaning of the company_id in items table?

Comment: About product 3. Table does not have this product. It's just example. And company_id field in items table means that this products belong that company which has id.

Comment: created_at is a timestamp or a date?
If it's a date it's ok to use EXTRACT or MONTH(my_field)
If it's a timestamp then you have to convert it to a date like FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at)